# Laravel Blade Multiple Values in DB Table

Tags: php, database, laravel, view

Little question: Currently I've a route

> Route::get('update/{id?}', 'SessionController@onClick');

That loads with this function:

```php
public function onClick($id, Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $user = User::where('userRooms', $id)->first();

    return view('sessions.cards')->with('user', $user);
}
```

I want that my blade view displays all users that have access to this room, currently I hard coded everything. My question is now, what do I have to write down in my code so that users have access to multiple rooms and not just one(userRooms row in my db for `User::Class`) & how I can display all users that have this room?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly. Try this way:

```php
public function onClick($id, Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $users = User::where('userRooms', $id)->get();

    return view('sessions.cards', [
        'users' => $users,
    ]);
}
```